# Using Mashape APIs with Volley or HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, android-studio, mashape

Can anyone point me in the right direction or demonstrate how to make a request to Mashape using an API key without Unirest?

I hope to make a JSON request to a Mashape API simply using the HttpURLConnection class or perhaps Android REST libraries like OkHttp or Volley, but I cant figure out how to structure the request, or if it is even possible without using Mashape's Unirest library.

This is how they recommend to create Unirest requests:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/incredible/definitions")
  .header("X-Mashape-Key", "**********apikey************")
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .asJson();
```

Im trying to avoid Unirest because it seems like a pain to set up and because the great CommonsWare himself stated Unirest should be avoided for Android: 
[Does anyone have an example of an android studio project that import Unirest via gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638676/does-anyone-have-an-example-of-an-android-studio-project-that-import-unirest-via)

I am actually trying to use the same api and with the same circumstances as Beginner in this question:
[Trying to fetch JSON with Android using Unirest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808878/trying-to-fetch-json-with-android-using-unirest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, my answer is what you are looking for.

I used Volley library, you need to add a dependency: `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String uri = Uri.parse("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/incredible/definitions")
    .buildUpon()
    .build().toString();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "response: " + response);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VolleyError", error.toString());
        }

    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("X-Mashape-Key", "<API_KEY>");
            params.put("Accept", "text/plain");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```